# What is the difference, if any, between 필업 and 졸업?

Tags: word-usage

I learned a word 필업식 but I'm not sure what is the difference between 필업 and 졸업. So far I have only heard the word 졸업. Is there any difference, even just a subtle nuance, between these two words?

Answer (score 2):

From [Naver online dictionary](https://dict.naver.com/search.dict?dicQuery=%ED%95%84%EC%97%85&query=%ED%95%84%EC%97%85&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=):

```
필업 (畢業)

[명사] 하고 있던 학업이나 사업을 마침.
[유의어] 졸업, 종업2
```

So it seems they are synonyms

If you go to the link above it also shows below the main entry:

```
필업 [오픈사전]

학업이나 작업을 마친다는 북한말
```

I don't know how exactly the 오픈사전 feature works, but it seems like viewer contribution and not necessarily from Naver. However, Naver seems to have kept this entry up so perhaps it means they deem this accurate.

Comment: So is the only difference that 필업 is used in NK? I heard it from a person in SK, but I'm not sure how often it is used in SK.

Comment: @Blaszard I'm not really sure about that I just went by what was given in Naver dictionary. Perhaps more research into this will make it clearer. Maybe the word is just more commonly used in NK.

Comment: I tried Google search on "필업" and the first result is Naver dictionary, the fourth is this very question :) and all others are either brand name or something related to cosmetics ("fill-up"?). So I'm skeptical how often the word is actually used in South Korea. I have certainly never heard of it myself.

Comment: I am getting this : https://ko.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ED%95%84%EC%97%85

Answer (score 2):

I'm Korean and  I've never used "필업" in my life for more than 30 years.

I think "졸업" is something that happens in school and "필업" is something that includes happens personally.

"졸업" is a word that follows the existence of students and schools, "필업" isn't.

For example, if my grandfather had a "졸업식", I could expect him to have attended school and had a graduation ceremony at school, but if he had a "필업식", I can't be sure if he did it at school.

I don't know how it is in NK, It only applies to SK.

Answer (score 2):

졸업 (卒業) means graduation. 필업 (畢業) is [a Chinese word equivalent to 졸업](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%A2%E6%A5%AD), and not used in modern Korea, at least not in common publication. Both [Sejong corpus](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hansaem-Kim/publication/267300052_Korean_National_Corpus_in_the_21st_Century_Sejong_Project/links/562f7a7908ae0077ccc9a97a/Korean-National-Corpus-in-the-21st-Century-Sejong-Project.pdf) and [Yonsei corpus](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hansaem-Kim/publication/311339692_Construction_of_Yonsei_20th_Century_Corpus%27/links/5de70c5892851c83645fce86/Construction-of-Yonsei-20th-Century-Corpus.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=started_experiment_milestone&origin=journalDetail) have zero occurrences of it ([Sejong search engine](http://kkma.snu.ac.kr/search), [Yonsei search engine](https://ilis.yonsei.ac.kr/corpus/#/search/)).

[image: Sejong search result]

[image: Yonsei search result]